# Custom SSIS component - method not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have internally developed SSIS component and trying to port it to SSIS 2016. Issue I have is that component is shown in SSIS Toolbox, but once I try to open component UI with double click, I get exception "method not found" with the method signature (method from my assembly). Exception is raised in component UI class.

Environment:

- VS 2015
- SSDT 17.2
- SSIS project configured for SQL 2016
- machine.config for both 32 and 64bit framework customized for
  assembly binding SQL Server assemblies from version 10 to 13 (see
  below for reason behind this)

VS Solution overview (legacy):

- separate C# projects for component, UI class, form (component UI) and
  logic behind form
- .NET version for component and UI projects is 4.0 and for form and
  logic projects 3.5
- References in C# projects for components and UI class use SQL Server dlls version 13, others use version 10 (SQL Server 2008) - this approach is already successfully used when ported from 2008 to 2012

Already checked:

- UITypeName is good
- when debugging component, it shows that assembly with "missing"
  method is already loaded and it is a good one (VS - Debug - Window - Modules)
- confirmed that "missing" method exists using intermediate window (visual check
  of method signature, declaring types and respective modules types are
  loaded from)
- EmbedInteropTypes in csproj files set to true for references (the same with false)
- Successfully opened package from console application, found custom component
  instance and opened its UI.

Since exception is raised when calling "missing" method located in my assembly the only thing I can imagine is that it can't find my dll or does not recognize types (defined in SSIS assemblies). Yet, reflection and VS Modules windows shows that everything exists.

Does anyone have any idea on how to overcome this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my answer, maybe someone will find it useful.

Seems like there is a problem with VS 2015 and/or SSDT 17.2. Tried repair, uninstall and install for both software and id didn't help. Uninstalling SSSDT 17.2 and installing SSDT 16.5 for VS 2015 helped. After this, exactly the same deployment process for my SSIS components, and exactly the same assembly versions worked just fine. So only thing that I can identify as change is version of SSDT.

Unfortunately, I don't know the particular reason for this behavior and I don't have any more time to invest to find out. Hope this will help someone, too.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add your dll to GAC . for more informations : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac

Comment: SSIS component related assemblies are in GAC and in appropriate folders  since components are visible in SSIS toolbox. My other assemblies are in GAC, As stated in question, VS, Debug, Windows, Modules shows that assemblies are loaded from appropriate locations..

Comment: Consider summarising the answer from the link for future proofing

Comment: sorry if my answer wasn't clear , my main job is to develop SSIS custom components . for this particular problem there are two things , either the assembly is not in GAC or you deployed an old assemby that doesn't include you method in GAC thus you need to recompile your dll and update it in GAC .

Comment: @dijikstra, seems like we had similar jobs not so long ago :) I agree that your answer is the most logical one. 

Unfortunately, it didn't help me because i had already checked it many times in previous sleepless days and nights :) Anyway, see my answer, just posted it for others for the future.

btw, i am not the one who downvoted your answer since it is perfectly logical and the first thing that should be checked in this case. Thank You very much for your effort!